# Raspberry Pi sending unwanted bytes at bootup

Tags: serial-port, raspberry-pi

While working on my first Raspberry Pi project, I need to send serial data to a bunch of Atmel AVR controllers (12x 90S2313). The TX of the Raspberry is level shifted to TTL level and all of the AVRs listen on their RX port. I send tiny packets over this "bus" which carries address, data and checksum. The AVRs listen and act if addressed. This AVR hardware is old, proven, bugfree (it has been running for 1,5 years controlled by a PC's serial port).

BUT: Even though I modified /boot/cmdline.txt and /etc/inittab the Raspberry STILL shoots out bytes at boot (not sure what, but I see them passing by on my oscilloscope; *appears* to be at 38400 baud).

This jams up the AVR controllers (and all of them at once!), probably because they see a command to program their own address in EEPROM and then just to and wait to be hard-resetted. If I connect the raspberry after boot all works like a charm.

Does anyone know what is sent? Is there any way to disable the sending of these bytes at bootup of the Raspberry?